# How to add if on rerender to select any template

Tags: apex, visualforce, rerender, datatable, view

i have a page visual force:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!listItems}" var="item" id="theTable"
    rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" columns="2">
        <apex:facet name="caption">Archivos</apex:facet>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">Name </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!item.fileName}"/>
        </apex:column>

        <apex:column >
            <apex:facet name="header">links</apex:facet>
            <apex:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-custom" value="" action="{!showPopup}" rerender="{!IF( String.valueOf(item.name) == 'ee','tstpopup2','tstpopup')}">
                 <apex:param name="url" value="{!item.name}" assignTo="{!paramValue}"/>
                 <i style="color: black" class="fas fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </apex:commandLink>
            
            <a class="btn btn-custom" href="{!item.mediaLink}" target="_blank" >
                <i style="color: black" class="fas fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
        </apex:column>

    </apex:dataTable>
```

I have two template for open images or open pdf ("tstpopup" and "tstpopup2")

i need apply any template for row

```
rerender="{!IF( String.valueOf(item.name) == 'ee','tstpopup2','tstpopup')}"
```

But i get error message: "Unknown property 'AccountStandardController.item'"

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Apex methods in Visualforce. You need to use the formula syntax.

```
rerender="{!IF(item.name='ee','tstpopup2','tstpopup')}"
```